# EGit has removed files from workspace

Tags: eclipse, egit

I have created Git repository outside of Eclipse. And made commit. Now I don't have files in my workspace, but have them in git directory. How to keep them in both places? And what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should keep and reference files from your git working tree, not the one in Eclipse workspace.

See the section "[Starting from existing Git Repositories](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Starting_from_existing_Git_Repositories) "

[image: Add Git repo]

After, you will be able to see those file in your Eclipse workspace, even though they are still in your local file system.